# Fisheye distortion rectification with lookup table

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, distortion, perspectivecamera, fisheye

I have a fisheye lens:

[image: curved chess]

I would like to undistort it. I apply the FOV model:

```
rd = 1 / ω * arctan (2 * ru * tan(ω / 2))   //Equation 13
ru = tan(rd * ω) / 2 / tan(ω / 2)           //Equation 14
```

as found in equations (13) and (14) of the INRIA paper "Straight lines have to be straight" https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00267247/document.

The code implementation is the following:

```
Point2f distortPoint(float w, float h, float cx, float cy, float omega, Point2f input) {
    //w = width of the image
    //h = height of the image
    //cx = center of the lens in the image, aka w/2
    //cy = center of the lens in the image, aka h/2

    Point2f tmp = new Point2f();

    //We normalize the coordinates of the point
    tmp.x = input.x / w - cx / w;
    tmp.y = input.y / h - cy / h;

    //We apply the INRIA key formula (FOV model)
    double ru = sqrt(tmp.x * tmp.x + tmp.y * tmp.y);
    double rd = 1.0f / omega * atan(2.0f * ru * tan(omega / 2.0f));

    tmp.x *= rd / ru;
    tmp.y *= rd / ru;

    //We "un-normalize" the point
    Point2f ret = new Point2f();
    ret.x = (tmp.x + cx / w) * w;
    ret.y = (tmp.y + cy / h) * h;

    return ret;
}
```

I then used the OpenCV remap function:

```
//map_x and map_y are computed with distortPoint
remap(img, imgUndistorted, map_x, map_y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
```

I managed to get the distortion model from the lens manufacturer. It's a table of image_height as a function of the field angle:

```
Field angle(deg)    Image Height (mm)
0                   0
1                   height1
2                   height2
3                   height3
...
89                  height89
90                  height90
```

To give an idea, each height is small and inferior to 2mm.

I found an interesting paper here: https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01073-flexible-architecture-fisheye-correction-automotive-rear-view-cameras.pdf

How can I modify my pixel-unit undistortion function to factor in the mm-unit table provided by the manufacturer in order to have the most accurate possible undistorted image?

Comment: This looks interesting, but on a mobile here i'm not that invested in all the reading. Is it possible that instead of linking thode papers, to try commenting your code well and use descriptive variable names?

Comment: Well, I extracted the key formula from the INRIA paper. The code is the implementation of the formula. I'm not sure what you are expecting more.

Comment: Do you know the camera sensor's size accurately? In that case conversion pixel/mm should be pretty straightforward

Comment: Yes, I have the pixel size on the sensor (1.4um x 1.4um) and I have also the image area. So how do I use such data to answer my question?

Comment: @gregoiregentil, In *general* I am expecting that if you commented your code and used descriptive variable names more that you might receive more interest in your query - i.e. the solution you're after :). Not garunteed, but it stands to reason ...

Comment: I have comments on quasi each line of the code and I think that w h cx cy input ret are pretty descriptive variable names. We are spoiling the comments on this question.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to undistort the image but you call `distortPoint` with eq. 13? Shouldn't you call eq. 14?