# Reverse fisheye radial distortion using Field of View model

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, distortion, fisheye

Let's suppose I have this distorted image taken from a fisheye camera with 185º FoV.

*Image taken from [Proc. IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP), pp. 1541-1545, Shanghai, China, March 2016](https://lms.lnt.de/fisheyedataset/).*

[image: distorted]

I want to undistort it using the FoV model explained in [Frederic Devernay, Olivier Faugeras. Straight lines have to be straight: automatic calibration
and removal of distortion from scenes of structured enviroments. Machine Vision and Applications, Springer Verlag, 2001, 13 (1), pp.14-24](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00267247/document), concretely in equations 13 and 14.

```
rd = 1 / ω * arctan (2 * ru * tan(ω / 2))   // Equation 13
ru = tan(rd * ω) / (2 * tan(ω / 2))         // Equation 14
```

I've implemented it in OpenCV and I can't achieve it to work. I interpret `rd` as the distorted distance of a point from the optical center, and `ru` as the new undistorted distance.

---

I let you a full minimal project.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#define W (185*CV_PI/180)

cv::Mat undistortFishEye(const cv::Mat &distorted, const float w)
{
    cv::Mat map_x, map_y;
    map_x.create(distorted.size(), CV_32FC1);
    map_y.create(distorted.size(), CV_32FC1);

    int Cx = distorted.cols/2;
    int Cy = distorted.rows/2;

    for (int x = -Cx; x < Cx; ++x) {
        for (int y = -Cy; y < Cy; ++y) {
            double rd = sqrt(x*x+ y*y);
            double ru = tan(rd*w) / (2*tan(w/2));
            map_x.at<float>(y+Cy,x+Cx) = ru/rd * x + Cx;
            map_y.at<float>(y+Cy,x+Cx) = ru/rd * y + Cy;
        }
    }

    cv::Mat undistorted;
    remap(distorted, undistorted, map_x, map_y, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    return undistorted;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::Mat im_d = cv::imread(<your_image_path>, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::imshow("Image distorted", im_d);

    cv::Mat im_u = undistortFishEye(im_d, W);
    cv::imshow("Image undistorted", im_u);

    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the error is in the FoV model input values. For example, the left top pixel `(-575,-543)` has `rd = 790,87`, and the FoV model returns me `ru = 0,012`.

Comment: Check this it might help you:

Comment: https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/blob/e761e802c6382bfe7c09f5f2db342c7a89209348/ptam/src/ATANCamera.cc#L52

Comment: @Ja_cpp Yes, it might be helpful. I've checked it and [invrtrans(double r)](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/blob/e761e802c6382bfe7c09f5f2db342c7a89209348/ptam/include/ptam/ATANCamera.h#L161) returns `equation 14`. Later, [Unproject](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/blob/e761e802c6382bfe7c09f5f2db342c7a89209348/ptam/src/ATANCamera.cc#L137) does the same that my code: `[xu, yu] = ru / rd * [xd, yd]`. Near to the optical center it assumes that there is no distortion, so it only undistorts when `(rd > 0.01)`. The only different thing I can see is how it calculates `rd`. Lets try

Comment: @Ja_cpp [PTAM](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/blob/e761e802c6382bfe7c09f5f2db342c7a89209348/ptam/src/ATANCamera.cc#L142) divides the distorted coordinates between the focal length `f` to normalize it: `rd = sqrt((xd/f)^2 + (yd/f)^2)`. The focal length is in pixel units. The [dataset](https://lms.lnt.de/fisheyedataset/) tells that the camera has `f=1.8mm`, an image resolution of `1088x1088` and a sensor size of `5.20mm`. So I calculate the focal length in pixel units as `1.8 / (5.20/1088)`. The undistortion isn't still working. Do you see any wrong step?

Comment: Well everything seems to be okay, I don't really know!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438241/fisheye-distortion-rectification-with-lookup-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only skimmed through the paper you linked, so I am not sure I got it right, but it looks like three things are wrong with your implementation:

1. You should use only half of your FOV angle as the `W` parameter (the algorithm operates in some radial coordinates, calculating distance from the center, so the angle should also be from the center, which gives half the angle).
2. You calculate `ru` and `rd` wrong: `ru` should be the distance, then `rd` should be according to Eq.(13). This is because you do inverse mapping: you create an empty image, then for every `(x, y)`-point of it you have to pick a color from the distorted image - you do that by distorting the `(x, y)` and look where it points at the distorted image, then map that color onto the original non-distorted `(x, y)` coordinates. Doing direct mapping (e. g. for every `(x, y)` of the distorted image move it into calculated location on the non-distorted image) gives visual artifacts, because not all target pixels are necessarily covered.
3. You forgot to normalize the radial coordinates, have to divide them by `Cx`, `Cy`, respectively, do the transform, then de-normalize by multiplying back.

There could also be some implicit conversion of `double` to `int`, but I am not sure - could never remember the rules about that, I just try not to mix `int`'s and `double`'s in the same equation, feel free to convert those `Cx, Cy` back to `int` if it works for you. Anyhow, this seems to work (both versions of `undistortFishEye` function give the same result, so use whichever you like better):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#define W (185/2*CV_PI/180)

cv::Mat undistortFishEye(const cv::Mat &distorted, const float w)
{
    cv::Mat map_x, map_y;
    map_x.create(distorted.size(), CV_32FC1);
    map_y.create(distorted.size(), CV_32FC1);

    double Cx = distorted.cols / 2.0;
    double Cy = distorted.rows / 2.0;

    for (double x = -1.0; x < 1.0; x += 1.0/Cx) {
        for (double y = -1.0; y < 1.0; y += 1.0/Cy) {
            double ru = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
            double rd = (1.0 / w)*atan(2.0*ru*tan(w / 2.0));

            map_x.at<float>(y*Cy + Cy, x*Cx + Cx) = rd/ru * x*Cx + Cx;
            map_y.at<float>(y*Cy + Cy, x*Cx + Cx) = rd/ru * y*Cy + Cy;
        }
    }

    cv::Mat undistorted;
    remap(distorted, undistorted, map_x, map_y, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    return undistorted;
}

cv::Mat undistortFishEye2(const cv::Mat &distorted, const float w)
{
    cv::Mat map_x, map_y;
    map_x.create(distorted.size(), CV_32FC1);
    map_y.create(distorted.size(), CV_32FC1);

    double cx = distorted.cols / 2.0;
    double cy = distorted.rows / 2.0;

    for (int x = 0; x < distorted.cols; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < distorted.rows; ++y)
        {
            double rx = (x - cx) / cx;
            double ry = (y - cy) / cy;
            double ru = sqrt(rx*rx + ry*ry);
            //TODO: check for ru == 0.0

            double rd = (1.0 / w)*atan(2.0*ru*tan(w/2.0));
            double coeff = rd / ru;
            rx *= coeff;
            ry *= coeff;
            map_x.at<float>(y, x) = rx*cx + cx;
            map_y.at<float>(y, x) = ry*cy + cy;
        }
    }

    cv::Mat undistorted;
    remap(distorted, undistorted, map_x, map_y, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    return undistorted;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::Mat im_d = cv::imread("C:/projects/test_images/fisheye/library.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::imshow("Image distorted", im_d);

    cv::Mat im_u = undistortFishEye(im_d, W);
    cv::imshow("Image undistorted", im_u);

    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

[image]

Big parts of the original image are lost during the transformation - is it supposed to be so? Or should the algorithm still map them somewhere? I tried transforming it onto a bigger target image, it got really stretched at the edges:
[image]

Comment: It sounds really nice, the three corrections have sense. I'd use the first implementation, it's smarter and surely a bit faster. About the loss of information, yes... `remap` returns an image of the same size as the original. This is not a problem for me, I want to use the undistorted function for a group of features in the image. The visualization of the undistorted image was a way to check that the undistortion was working.

Comment: I think there are bugs in the first implementations, `for (double y = -1.0; y < 1.0; y += 1.0/Cx)` should be `1.0/Cy`, of course,  and then `rd/ru * y*Cx + Cy` should be `rd/ru * y*Cy + Cy`. Gonna check later and fix my answer.